# GCM service stops working when I implement Robospice with Spring module

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, robospice

I have implemented a standard GCM client following the instructions on google developers page ([Gcm implementation](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html)). Push messages have worked great no problem there. But then I implemented Robospice REST lib in the application and GCM stopped working. I am sure it does not work because of Robospice because as soon as I remove the code for SpiceManager GCM starts working.

API calls via Robospice Spring module work fine. This is my declaration of Robospice services:

```
enter<receiver
                  android:name="com.clover.spika.enterprise.chat.services.gcm.GcmBroadcastRe    ceiver"
        android:exported="true"
                android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action      android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action      android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category     android:name="com.clover.spika.enterprise.chat.gcm" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service     android:name="com.clover.spika.enterprise.chat.services.gcm.GcmIntentService" />
    <service
           android:name="com.clover.spika.enterprise.chat.services.robospice.Jackson2   SpiceService"
        android:exported="false" />
    <service    android:name="com.clover.spika.enterprise.chat.services.custom.PoolingServ   ice" /> code here
```

This is my custom spice service:

```
package com.clover.spika.enterprise.chat.services.robospice;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.http.ContentCodingType;
 import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
import         org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import android.app.Application;
import android.app.Notification;

import com.octo.android.robospice.SpringAndroidSpiceService;
import com.octo.android.robospice.persistence.CacheManager;
import     com.octo.android.robospice.persistence.exception.CacheCreationException;
import     com.octo.android.robospice.persistence.springandroid.json.jackson.JacksonO    bjectPersisterFactory;

public class Jackson2SpiceService extends SpringAndroidSpiceService {

// private static final int WEBSERVICES_TIMEOUT = 10000;

@Override
public RestTemplate createRestTemplate() {

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate() {

        @Override
        protected ClientHttpRequest createRequest(URI url, HttpMethod method) throws IOException {
            ClientHttpRequest request = super.createRequest(url, method);
            HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders();
            headers.setAcceptEncoding(ContentCodingType.ALL);
            return request;
        }
    };

    // bug on http connection for Android < 2.2
    // http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html
    // but still a problem for upload with Spring-android on android 4.1
    // System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");

    // // set timeout for requests
    // ClientHttpRequestFactory factory = restTemplate.getRequestFactory();
    // if (factory instanceof HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory) {
    // HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory advancedFactory =
    // (HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory) factory;
    // advancedFactory.setConnectTimeout(WEBSERVICES_TIMEOUT);
    // advancedFactory.setReadTimeout(WEBSERVICES_TIMEOUT);
    // } else if (factory instanceof SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory) {
    // SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory advancedFactory =
    // (SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory) factory;
    // advancedFactory.setConnectTimeout(WEBSERVICES_TIMEOUT);
    // advancedFactory.setReadTimeout(WEBSERVICES_TIMEOUT);
    // }

    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    FormHttpMessageConverter formHttpMessageConverter = new FormHttpMessageConverter();
    // StringHttpMessageConverter stringHttpMessageConverter = new
    // StringHttpMessageConverter();

    List<MediaType> supportedMediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
    supportedMediaTypes.add(MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
    supportedMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    // stringHttpMessageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(supportedMediaTypes);
    jsonConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(supportedMediaTypes);

    final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> listHttpMessageConverters = restTemplate.getMessageConverters();

    listHttpMessageConverters.add(jsonConverter);
    listHttpMessageConverters.add(formHttpMessageConverter);
    // listHttpMessageConverters.add(stringHttpMessageConverter);

    restTemplate.setMessageConverters(listHttpMessageConverters);

    return restTemplate;
}

@Override
public CacheManager createCacheManager(Application application) throws CacheCreationException {

    CacheManager cacheManager = new CacheManager();
    JacksonObjectPersisterFactory jacksonObjectPersisterFactory = new     JacksonObjectPersisterFactory(application);
    cacheManager.addPersister(jacksonObjectPersisterFactory);

    return cacheManager;
}

@Override
public Notification createDefaultNotification() {
    return null;
}

}
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem? I can post additional code if it is needed.

Comment: It's about the `Robospice`, you can also put your issue [here](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/issues)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue, it was not robospice or gcm fault, it was a thing in our server handling.

The thing is that we read some values from User-Agent header that i was not aware of and i did not set it to the OkHttp client.